# ONOS Service Start FrameworkEvent Error and GUI not ready yet

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-18.04, sdn, onos

I have installed ONOS 2.3.0 on an Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 virtual machine running on Hyper-V following this steps (taken from [here](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Requirements) and [here](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Installing+on+a+single+machine)):

1. Firstly, I have installed Java 11 (openjdk-11-jdk and openjdk-11-jre), maven and curl;
2. then I have downloaded ONOS 2.3.0 from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/onosproject/onos-releases/2.3.0/onos-2.3.0.tar.gz) and extracted it with `tar xzf onos-2.3.0.tar.gz`;
3. lastly, I exported the required environment variable `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`.

When I try to launch it using the command `./onos-service start` (tested both from a normal user and sudo), it gives me the following errors:

```
21:54:57.869 ERROR [onos-core-net] FrameworkEvent ERROR - org.onosproject.onos-core-net
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory returned null. (Component: org.onosproject.store.cfg.DistributedComponentConfigStore (6))
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:247) org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)
[...]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1373)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[...]
21:54:57.881 WARN  [NettyMessagingService] Failed to bind TCP server to port 0.0.0.0:9876 due to {}
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[...]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
21:54:57.899 ERROR [onos-core-primitives] bundle org.onosproject.onos-core-primitives:2.3.0 (192)[org.onosproject.store.atomix.impl.AtomixManager(115)] : The activate method has thrown an exception
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
[...]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:132)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:563)
    ... 12 more
```

Connecting to karaf instance with `ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost` confirm that ONOS is working (at least partially), the web interface login loads, but after login it hangs saying that `ONOS GUI not ready yet... please stand by...`.

Does anyone has an idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 19-03-2020**: I have prepared another virtual machine following exactly the same steps on another PC using VirtualBox and lower virtual resources assigned, and it works. Honestly i don't understand why it fails on the Hyper-V configuration.

**UPDATE 20-03-2020**: I have reinstalled Ubuntu configuring the network directly from the installer, and prerequisites and dependecies of ONOS offline (downloaded on another machine via `sudo apt install --download-only <package-name>`) and it worked. I think the problem was related to something in the network configuration that didn't let him recognize its own process on port 9876 (see the WARN above).
Hope this can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem. ONOS is locked to the IP at first install. I grepped for my IP in the /onos folder and was able to reset the binding by deleting the following files that contained the IP. They were rebuilt at next ONOS run.

```
grep -rl 192.168. --exclude=*.log ~/onos

rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/data/partitions/1/raft-partition-1.conf
rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/data/partitions/1/raft-partition-1.meta
rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/data/partitions/1/.raft-partition-1.lock
rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/system/partitions/1/.system-partition-1.lock
rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/system/partitions/1/system-partition-1.conf
rm ~/onos/apache-karaf-4.2.9/data/db/partitions/system/partitions/1/system-partition-1.meta
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue after changing the IP address of the controller (Host machine).

The quick way to solve it is to set the IP controller as it was (Static)

then reboot your machine

after putting the URL (YourIP:8181/onos/ui/index.html)

Karaf will ask you for login in credentials, use (username:karaf/password:karaf)

then on ONOS's login page, use onos/rocks as credentials.

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Would you put some details of "set the IP controller as it was (Static)"?